# didSelectRowAt remembers the first element ( indexPath) when using searchBar

Tags: swift, searchbar

I have a Master-Detail app where Master has a UITable view, with a Search bar, and when clicked on goes to the Detail view, which has a web view of the master that was clicked on.

Everything goes great until Search is used.  For example, I type in the Search bar "We" for "Westminster Savings Credit Union".  Search shows this as showing in the first row, which on initial load was belonging to "Annie" which was on the first line.

I have filteredData[indexPath.row] which shows "Westminster Savings Credit Union" which is linked to a UIImage, so the image shows correctly of "Westminster Savings Credit Union", however, the urlString still shows that of "Annie"'s website.  I'm not sure how I could get the corresponding website for "Westminster Savings Credit Union".

I have posted code for didSelectRowAt, and SearchBar.  Thanks.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) {
    var object2: AnyObject?

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {


        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0...MyVariables.count-1:
            do {
                if (searchActive == true) {
                object2 = filteredData[indexPath.row] as AnyObject
                print("filtereddata", filteredData[indexPath.row]) //prints Westminster Savings Credit Union
                //MyVariables.urlString = ?                        //not sure how to assign it to urlString
                print("urlString in didselectrow", MyVariables.urlString)
                MyVariables.companyImage = UIImage(named: filteredData[indexPath.row])// correct image
            }
                else
                {
                    MyVariables.urlString = [MyVariables.siteAddresses![indexPath.row]]
                    print("MyVariablessiteAddresses",[MyVariables.siteAddresses![indexPath.row]])
                    print("urlString in didselectrow", MyVariables.urlString)
                    MyVariables.companyImage = UIImage(named: MyVariables.test![indexPath.row])
                }
            }
        default:
            do {
                MyVariables.urlString = ["https://sunwoodsquare.com/store-directory/"]
                MyVariables.companyImage = UIImage(named: MyVariables.test![indexPath.row])
            }
        }
    }
}


public func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {



    filteredData = (MyVariables.test?.filter { $0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil })!


    if(filteredData.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Why do you needlessly get the cell for the selected row and then not use it?

Answer (score 1):

The title is misleading. The searchBar is not remembering the first row. It's a problem in your implementation. Since you are not assigning any value to `MyVariables.urlString` under `if (searchActive == true)`, it will just use the last value assigned to it.

As for how you can access said value under `if (searchActive == true)`, you will have to create a `filteredSiteAddresses` array. When you update the `filteredData` array in `searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)`, you'll have to update `filteredSiteAddresses` as well. Then under `if (searchActive == true)`, you can do something like

```
MyVariables.urlString = [MyVariables.filteredSiteAddresses![indexPath.row]]
```